# How to increment an Int value in a Map with getOrElseUpdate?

Tags: scala, dictionary, integer, assign, mutablemap

I can update a mutable.Map value with `+=`:

```
scala> val map = mutable.Map[Int,Int]()
map: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map()

scala> map(5) = 5

scala> map
res55: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(5 -> 5)

scala> map(5) += 1

scala> map
res57: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(5 -> 6)
```

But I can't use `+=` with `getOrElseUpdate` and I don't understand why:

```
scala> map.getOrElseUpdate(5, 0) += 1
<console>:16: error: value += is not a member of Int
  Expression does not convert to assignment because receiver is not assignable.
map.getOrElseUpdate(5, 0) += 1
                          ^
```

I know I've used a `mutable.SortedMap` with `mutable.ArrayBuffer` values before and it let me use that type's `+=` operation with `getOrElseUpdate` with no problem. Is there something like `mutable.Int` that I'm supposed to use?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In scala you don't get semantics of obtaining "reference" of a variable and it is because good style of scala is when you don't mutate variables on your own, so you can't do this in this way. Rather than this you can describe mutation with function rather than directly mutating variable in this way:

```scala
  import scala.collection.mutable
  val map = mutable.Map.empty[Int,Int]
  val yourKey: Int = ???
  map.updateWith(yourKey){
    case Some(i) => Some(i+1)
    case None => Some(1)
  }
```

Here i used this: [https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.6/scala/collection/mutable/Map.html#updateWith(key:K)(remappingFunction:Option[V]=%3EOption[V]):Option[V]](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.6/scala/collection/mutable/Map.html#updateWith(key:K)(remappingFunction:Option%5BV%5D=%3EOption%5BV%5D):Option%5BV%5D)

Also +, += and +: functions in array buffer and other mutable collections have other semantics.